# How to set styling of div based on another div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a unique case here. So i have 2 divs, one on the left and one on right. How can i make it so that if the height of left div exceeds the height of the div on right, the function should make the heights equal and hide any text for the left div. So if i calculate the offsetheight on load and for one on right is 443 px and one on left is 583 px, it should make both heights equal and height the rest 140px of data of left one.

I created a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qeqbNw?editors=1111)

```js
var text = document.getElementById('overflow_text')

function mounted() {
  var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle_text')
  var offsetDiv = document.getElementById('offset_height')
  var offsetDivHeight = offsetDiv.offsetHeight + 'px'
  var textHeight = text.offsetHeight + 'px'
  console.log(textHeight)
  console.log(offsetDivHeight)
  if (textHeight > offsetHeight) {
    text.style.maxHeight = offsetDivHeight
    text.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    text.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis'
    text.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap'
  }
}
```

```css
#toggle_text {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body onLoad='mounted()'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p id='overflow_text' class="readMore">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
          vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
          Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec
          congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis.
          Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas
          vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas
          vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas
          vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec</p>
        <span onClick="myFunction()" id="toggle_text">Read More</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p id="offset_height">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
          vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
          Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est,Donec vitae dui
          eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae
          scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl estDonec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So if you check the console, you will see what the heights of both divs are onLoad. Not sure how i can set the CSS through Javascript. Thank you in advance.
If any one has any other ideas on how to achieve this, i am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a bit tricky, since you cannot simply use `textOverflow: ellipsis` css property if your text has multiple lines.

First we set `height` of the `left` text container to the height of the `right` which is smaller. Then we have to shrink the number of words displayed inside the left container. We remove words from the end of the container until container's scrollHeight is smaller or equal to the container's height. 
In this way we know that the container has only as much words as it's able to display with restriction that it's no taller than the right container.

The drawback is that we remove overflowing words from the element so you're no longer able to get original content from this container.

```
function mounted() {
  var leftContainer = document.getElementById('overflow_text')
  var rightContainer = document.getElementById('offset_height')
  var rightOffsetHeight = rightContainer.offsetHeight;
  var leftOffsetHeight = leftContainer.offsetHeight;

  if (leftOffsetHeight > rightOffsetHeight) {
    leftContainer.style.height = rightOffsetHeight + "px"

    var wordArray = leftContainer.innerHTML.split(' ');
    while(leftContainer.scrollHeight > leftContainer.offsetHeight) {
        wordArray.pop();
        leftContainer.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: woahh!!! This is incredible. Accepting this as an answer, however could you pleas explain how's the logic with wordArray working exactly? You're splitting the innerHTML from which position?

Comment: So if i want to be able to click on read More to get the rest of the text to expand, it won't be possible?

Comment: It will, but you will have to store the full text either inside your model layer or somewhere inside html, e.g. as a data attribute of original text container.

Comment: I am sorry but i'm not sure if i fully understand. You mean like creating an object clone of the original text?

Comment: It could be a solution. In real application you would probably have the text rendered from javascript so it would be very easy to create onClick listener that would show full text when the button is clicked.

Comment: If you don't mind could you add a demo to hide/show the text because i've been trying to use style.display and push() but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Of course it would be viable and I suppose it's usually done in the way I described in the previous post.

Comment: The reason being is that i am not quite sure how the data is being returned which sucks. So i am trying to find if there is a way to push the truncated text back into wordArray.

Comment: Just store the text in the variable before it becomes truncated and then you may do with it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

> `if (textHeight > offsetHeight)`

`offsetHeight` is never defined. Do you mean `offsetDivHeight`?

> `text.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap'`

If you do this, all of the text in the div will be confined to one line.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZgBWbN) with these changes made.

Comment: Well if you can read the code, that is already being done. But as you can see not getting the desired result.

Comment: Editing my response.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement needs to use the variable name, `offsetDivHeight`.

Comment: oh wow. yes that helps. but how can i get the ellipses to show after a certain height? Maybe set a fixed height on container and set it to auto maybe on expanding?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This post would be better as a comment on the question instead of an answer post.